# How to force a new sorting of mapped array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, object, state

How can I create a button that is re-sorting an array of objects, from outside the `map()` function, while using the `useState()`, like this:

```
let [myArr, setMyArr] = React.useState([{x: 1, y: 5, z: 'cat'},{x: 3, y: 4, z: 'snake'},{x: 5, y: 3, z: 'fish'},{x: 2, y: 1, z: 'dog'},{x: 4, y: 1, z: 'parrot'}]);
return (
    <div>
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                setMyArr(myArr.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y))
            }}
        >
            Resort by Y
        </button>
        {myArr.sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x).map(myArr => myArr.z)}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a `.sort(` after the button, only thing you need to do is update the array state after clicking the button **without mutating**

```
<div>
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      setMyArr([...myArr.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)]);
    }}
  >
    Resort by Y
  </button>
  {myArr.map(myArr => myArr.z)}
</div>
```

here is a [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m2dw4j)

[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will return the same array reference with sorted objects inside, as of your code when you try to do `setMyArr(myArr.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y))` onClick of the button it will give the same array reference with sorted objects and assign to the state (mutating). That's not gonna work (why react will check previous and after variable are same or not to trigger a render, since the reference to the array didn't get changed, render is not gonna happen) so you have to give the new state as a new reference to a sorted array (non mutating state) so `setMyArr([...myArr.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)]);` will create a new array and assign to the state. (with [...array] you can create a brand new array)

Comment: Though it's probably irrelevant in this case, but you're still mutating the current state. It should be: `setMyArr([...myArr].sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y));` Meaning, first copy, then sort.

Comment: Both works, i guess, in mycase I sorted it and create a new copy of the array (yeah kinda mutating), in your case create a new copy of the array and then sort it, but i guess your suggestion is good :)